# Symfony 3.3 - uncaught Twig Runtime Exception when attempting to access a flash message in a template

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a flashbag that's not guaranteed to actually have a message in it.  If it does have a message, I'd like to display it, otherwise just continue with rendering the template.  To that end, I have the following Twig `if` block:

```
{% if app.flashes.has('success') %}
    {% set flashbag = app.flashes.get('success') %}
    {% set message = flashbag[0] %}
    <div id="flash">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

An uncaught Twig Runtime Exception is occurring at the first line, leading me to believe my syntax is wrong.  I'm not sure what the correct syntax would be, however.

Comment: What version of symfony are you using? I get `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Array to string conversion").` as my error using your snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looping through it instead of setting a variable, and leave out the if statement:

```
{% for message in app.flashes('success') %}
    <div class="flash">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This may also need your attention: [New in Symfony 3.3: Improved flash messages](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-improved-flash-messages)